# html seo alternate Мультиязычность сайта

Tags: html, seo

Вопрос по поводу мультиязычности сайта. Есть сайт на двух языках. Например, наша базовая страница - http://www.example.com.ua на русском и http://www.example.com.ua/ua/  - на украинском. Переход через кнопку на страницу сайта с другим языком(другой html файл). Этих 3 строк LINK мне будет достаточно для того что бы сайт нормально отображался/индексировался в поске? Или нужно еще что-то добавлять? И правильно ли оформленные ссылок линк исходя из моего примера выше? + НА сколько я понимаю "х-default" заменяет каноникал и должен быть использован только один раз? (тоисть на других страницах нужно будет указать только два тега линк альтернейт без x-default).Спасибо.

например на мейн странице http://www.example.com.ua/, которая на русском языке:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-UA" href="http://www.example.com.ua/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ua-RU" href="http://www.example.com.ua/ua/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://www.example.com.ua/">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

разобрался сам))) спасибо

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru-UA" href="http://www.example.com.ua/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="uk-UA" href="http://www.example.com.ua/ua/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://www.example.com.ua/ua/" />
```

Comment: будет полезно для сообщетсва, если вы оставите ссылку на источник информации или документацию , который помог вам разобраться.